# angular2 kendo -grid column definition

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to create a column dictionary, but haven't found a way
to create column definitions programmatically. 
Answers that I have found doesn't allow reuse of the template that is inside the column definition and they are different.

For example look at these two possible column definitions

```
<kendo-grid-column>
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <div class="k-button" (click)="edit(dataItem)">
            <span class="k-icon k-i-pencil"></span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>


<kendo-grid-column field="anyField" >
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
        <div>
             {{dataItem.anyField}}
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngFor to translate your column definitions to kendo grid's.